# How to a extract binary file from resources?

Tags: c#, resources

I'm trying to copy a file in my WindowsFormsApp12
named `smth.cs` from a folder named `resources` to `C:\Users\1\Desktop\123`.

I've tried to use this code but it doesn't work:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(
    @"C:\Users\1\Desktop\123\smth.cs", WindowsFormsApp12.Properties.Resources.smth
);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what did you mean by extract? is it to copy from one place to another ?

Comment: yes, to copy my file from resources to "C:\Users\1\Desktop\123".

Comment: What does "it doest works" mean exactly?

Comment: it means I found it online, but it doesn't really fit

Comment: why u r using WriteAllBytes , the resources you get as a string , so basically you have a string and u want to write it's content to a file , u will need to use File.WriteAllText method , also to write to this location u have specified u will need administration permission (right click then run as admin)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    string source = @"c:\source\MyTest.txt";
    string destination = @"c:\destination\MyTest.txt";
    File.Copy(source , destination);
```

Comment: but what i must do if i want to compile my file with program ?